# Reading floats from DataInputStream is really slow on android

Tags: java, android, file, datainputstream

I'm trying to read a decently sized file on my android (Sony Experia Z3) and it takes much longer than I was hoping for. I have the following code:

```
DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
float[] values = new float[dataIn.available() / 4];

logInfo("Started");
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
int i = 0;
while(dataIn.available() > 0) {
    values[i++] = dataIn.readFloat();
}
double elapsed = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000.0;
logInfo("elapsed time in seconds: " + elapsed + " floats read: " + values.length);
```

Output:

```
Started
elapsed time in seconds: 52.594 floats read: 3421669
```

The file is 17,1 MB, should that really take a minute to read? Is there a way to improve the performance?

**Edit:**

Just as I posted this I tried to avoid dataIn.available and suddenly it only took 4 sec. Changed:

```
while(dataIn.available() > 0) {
```

To:

```
while(i < values.length) {
```

New result:

```
elapsed time in seconds: 3.842 floats read: 3421669
```

Comment: Get rid of the `available()` test, and catch `EOFException` instead. `available()` is not a valid test for end of file. Nor is it a measure of how much data there is in the stream. See the Javadoc.

Comment: Thanks @EJP Is it a risk to preallocate the float array using new float[dataIn.available() / 4];? Is there a better way?

Comment: Yes, for the reason I stated. Use `File.length()`.

Comment: Allright, thanks a lot!